# How to save this Form for later, storing serialized data in JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

**[Solved]**
I have big HTML Form with 2 Tables one small with static fields and names. The second Large table has dynamically added rows with button, all the fields in this large table have in row unique name + number for example: `sku_code_input_1`, what represents Row ID, which is also shown in first column. Because Row ID does not represents real row ID, because I had to add few "empty rows" where page breaks for printing.
This Code is will take all the values from this input fields and returns me string, what I believe is for POST purpose in Url.

```
     function returnArrayValues() {
        var countRow = $('#sku_details_list tr').length -3;
        var str = $( "#inboundList" ).serialize();
        
        $( "#results" ).text( countRow + " " + str); //just to show it on display
        }
      /* Results showed on screen:
      0 create_time=2020-12- 
    12T09%3A04&container_noS=MXASDOFSA&ic_numbS=IC06956251&customer_code=985652&
    unload_date=2020-12-02&
    unload_name=cxzczx&date_and_time=2020-12-10T09%3A24&
    sorting_date=2020-12-11&sorting_name=czxc&gate_numbe=95&
    putaway_date=2020-12-11&putaway_name=zxcasdas&old_ro_numb=&
    confirm_date=&confirm_name=&in_box_date=&in_box_name=&pallets_qtty_1=12&
    boxes_on_pallet_1=1&sku_code_input_1=1516566&expected_qtty_box_1=12&
    received_box_qtty_1=12&putaway_area_1=122.2.2.2&pallets_qtty_2=20&
    boxes_on_pallet_2=5&sku_code_input_2=KASDJ-XZC-56
    &expected_qtty_box_2=100&received_box_qtty_2=100&putaway_area_2=333.6.6.4
    ...... */
```

I do not know how I can convert, store this kind of Output, probably in JSON file, as storing this in MySQL database might be overtime little bit too much, considering there can be 174 rows.`container_noS`,`ic_numbS` and `date_and_time`are fields what are required, and these I would want to use as Key to return rest of the form.

I think the array should looks something like this? Where `Array[1]` would be data from different Form, and I could use the first 3 values to find what form I am looking for to call the values.

> Array[0]{{'container_noS':'MXASDOFSA', 'ic_numbS': 'IC06956251',
> 'date_and_time': '2020-12-10T09%3A24'} SubArray[]{'customer_code':
> '985652', 'unload_date': '2020-12-02', ...}}
>
> Array[1](https://pastebin.com/yPt6mrSY){{'container_noS':'XASDAS', 'ic_numbS': 'IC77777',
> 'date_and_time': '2020-10-11T09%3A24'} SubArray[]{'customer_code':
> '123452', 'unload_date': '2020-10-02', ...}}

[Full code here](https://pastebin.com/yPt6mrSY) or HTML table layout below:

```
<body class="print">
<form class="container-fluid" method="post" id="inboundList" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <div id="no-print" style="margin-left:10%;">
        <button type="button" id="save_button" style="margin: 0 20px 20px 0;" onclick="returnArrayValues()">Save</button>
        <button type="button" id="print_button" style="margin: 0 20px 20px 0;" onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
        <button type="reset" id="reset_button" style="margin: 0 20px 20px 0;">Reset Form</button>
        <button type="close" id="cancel_button" style="margin: 0 20px 20px 0;">Discard</button>
    
    </div>
    <div style="width:20.7cm;  background-color: yellow; page-break-inside:auto;  ;" id="printPageDiv"> <!-- Start of DIV what will be printed -->
    <div style="position:relative;"> <!-- Header of Page with logo and Container No. -->
    <img src='../../images/id_print_logo.png' height="72px" width="182px">
    <label>Created:<input type="datetime-local" step="60" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}" 
    id="create_time" name="create_time" readonly style="width:180px; text-align:center;" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i')?>"></input></label>
    
    <label style="font-size:15px;font_weight:bold;  margin-left: 20px">Container Number: 
        <input type="text" name="container_noS" id="container_noS" style="font-size:15px; font_weight:bold; text-align:center; width: 180px;" maxlength="16" required></input></label>
    </div>  
    <!-- IC Number with its Barcode  -->
    <div style="position:relative; margin-top:5px; height:2cm">
    <label style="float:right; font_weight:bold;width:250px; ">IC Number: <input required type="text" name="ic_numbS" id="ic_numbS" onchange="changeTest(this.form)" 
    maxlength="16" style="font-size:20px; font_weight:bold; text-align:center;"></input></label>
    <div id="insertBarcodeHere"></div>
    </div>  
<div class="row"></div> 
<table id="rcv_head_tmpl"> <!-- Start of header table -->
    <tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>Date: </th><th>Name: </th></tr>
    <tr><th>Client: </th><td><input type="text" name="customer_code"></input></td>
    <th>Unloading: </th><td><input type="date" name="unload_date"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="unload_name"></td></tr>
    
    <tr><th>Date and Time: </th><td><input type="datetime-local" step="60" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"  
    name="date_and_time" required></input></td>
    
    <th>Sorting: </th><td><input type="date" name="sorting_date"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sorting_name"></td></tr>
    
    <tr><th>Gate: </th><td><input type="text" name="gate_numbe"></input></td>
    <th>Put away: </th><td><input type="date" name="putaway_date"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="putaway_name"></td></tr>
    
    <tr><th>OLD RO: </th><td><input type="text" name="old_ro_numb"></input></td>
    <th>Confirmation: </th><td><input type="date" name="confirm_date"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="confirm_name"></td></tr>
    
    <tr><th></th><td></td>
    <th>Counting pcs in box: </th><td><input type="date" name="in_box_date"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="in_box_name"></td></tr>    

</table  > <!--end of header table -->
<table id="sku_details_list"  class="tablesorter" style=" border-spacing: 1px;"> <!-- Start of SKU list table -->

    <tr><th style="width: 3%;">ID: </th><th style="width: 8%;">Total Pallets: </th><th style="width: 8%;">Boxes on Pallet: </th><th style="width: 12%;">Old Location: </th>
    <th style="width: 20%;">SKU Code: </th><th style="width: 8%;">Expected Qtty: </th><th style="width: 8%;">Received Boxes: </th><th style="width: 12%;">Putaway Location: </th></tr>
    
    <tr><td>1</td><td><input type="text" name="pallets_qtty_1"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="boxes_on_pallet_1"></input></td>
                        <td id="return_oldLocation1"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="sku_code_input_1" onchange="showOldLocations(this.value,this)"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="expected_qtty_box_1"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="received_box_qtty_1"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="putaway_area_1"></input></td></tr>
        
    <tr><td>2</td><td><input type="text" name="pallets_qtty_2"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="boxes_on_pallet_2"></input></td>
                        <td id="return_oldLocation2"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="sku_code_input_2" onchange="showOldLocations(this.value,this)"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="expected_qtty_box_2"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="received_box_qtty_2"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="putaway_area_2"></input></td></tr>

</table> <!-- End of SKU list table -->
</div> <!-- div for page to be printed -->  
<button type="button" id="row_button">Add New Row</button>

</div>
  </form>
```

When I try different function for storing Data, I am getting `[object Object]` returned, When I convert this with serialize() which I believe is wrong, I will get same output as with my first function. So the question is still here, how I can read this `[object Object]` values, what I must believe should be correct output I am looking for.

```
 $('#inboundList').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); 
var form = $(this); 
form.children('input').each(function() {
    form.data($(this).attr('name'), $(this).attr('value'));
}); 
var xxx = stringify([form]);
$( "#results" ).text( xxx );
});
```

**UPDATE:** I am trying to use replacing of the = and & symbols, to make it as JSON Syntax.

```
 function returnArrayValues() {
var countRow = $('#sku_details_list tr').length -3;
var str = $( "#inboundList" ).serialize();
var resUlt = str.replace(/=&/g,'": "", "').replace(/=/g,'": "').replace(/&/g,'", "');

$( "#results" ).text( '"table_rows": "'+countRow + '", "' + resUlt + '"'); //just to show it on display

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `serializeArray` and `reduce` to convert the form data to an object:

```js
// ES5 version

var data = $('#inboundList').serializeArray()
  .reduce(function(accu, field) {
    accu[field.name] = field.value;
    return accu;
  }, {});

console.log(data);

// ES6 version

var data = $('#inboundList').serializeArray()
  .reduce((accu, {name, value}) => ({ ...accu, [name]: value }), {});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="container-fluid" method="post" id="inboundList" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <div id="no-print" style="margin-left:10%;">
        <button type="button" id="save_button" style="margin: 0 20px 20px 0;" onclick="returnArrayValues()">Save</button>
        <button type="button" id="print_button" style="margin: 0 20px 20px 0;" onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
        <button type="reset" id="reset_button" style="margin: 0 20px 20px 0;">Reset Form</button>
        <button type="close" id="cancel_button" style="margin: 0 20px 20px 0;">Discard</button>
    
    </div>
    <div style="width:20.7cm;  background-color: yellow; page-break-inside:auto;  ;" id="printPageDiv"> <!-- Start of DIV what will be printed -->
    <div style="position:relative;"> <!-- Header of Page with logo and Container No. -->
    <img src='../../images/id_print_logo.png' height="72px" width="182px">
    <label>Created:<input type="datetime-local" step="60" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}" 
    id="create_time" name="create_time" readonly style="width:180px; text-align:center;" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i')?>"></input></label>
    
    <label style="font-size:15px;font_weight:bold;  margin-left: 20px">Container Number: 
        <input type="text" name="container_noS" id="container_noS" style="font-size:15px; font_weight:bold; text-align:center; width: 180px;" maxlength="16" required></input></label>
    </div>  
    <!-- IC Number with its Barcode  -->
    <div style="position:relative; margin-top:5px; height:2cm">
    <label style="float:right; font_weight:bold;width:250px; ">IC Number: <input required type="text" name="ic_numbS" id="ic_numbS" onchange="changeTest(this.form)" 
    maxlength="16" style="font-size:20px; font_weight:bold; text-align:center;"></input></label>
    <div id="insertBarcodeHere"></div>
    </div>  
<div class="row"></div> 
<table id="rcv_head_tmpl"> <!-- Start of header table -->
    <tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>Date: </th><th>Name: </th></tr>
    <tr><th>Client: </th><td><input type="text" name="customer_code"></input></td>
    <th>Unloading: </th><td><input type="date" name="unload_date"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="unload_name"></td></tr>
    
    <tr><th>Date and Time: </th><td><input type="datetime-local" step="60" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"  
    name="date_and_time" required></input></td>
    
    <th>Sorting: </th><td><input type="date" name="sorting_date"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sorting_name"></td></tr>
    
    <tr><th>Gate: </th><td><input type="text" name="gate_numbe"></input></td>
    <th>Put away: </th><td><input type="date" name="putaway_date"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="putaway_name"></td></tr>
    
    <tr><th>OLD RO: </th><td><input type="text" name="old_ro_numb"></input></td>
    <th>Confirmation: </th><td><input type="date" name="confirm_date"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="confirm_name"></td></tr>
    
    <tr><th></th><td></td>
    <th>Counting pcs in box: </th><td><input type="date" name="in_box_date"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="in_box_name"></td></tr>    

</table  > <!--end of header table -->
<table id="sku_details_list"  class="tablesorter" style=" border-spacing: 1px;"> <!-- Start of SKU list table -->

    <tr><th style="width: 3%;">ID: </th><th style="width: 8%;">Total Pallets: </th><th style="width: 8%;">Boxes on Pallet: </th><th style="width: 12%;">Old Location: </th>
    <th style="width: 20%;">SKU Code: </th><th style="width: 8%;">Expected Qtty: </th><th style="width: 8%;">Received Boxes: </th><th style="width: 12%;">Putaway Location: </th></tr>
    
    <tr><td>1</td><td><input type="text" name="pallets_qtty_1"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="boxes_on_pallet_1"></input></td>
                        <td id="return_oldLocation1"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="sku_code_input_1" onchange="showOldLocations(this.value,this)"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="expected_qtty_box_1"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="received_box_qtty_1"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="putaway_area_1"></input></td></tr>
        
    <tr><td>2</td><td><input type="text" name="pallets_qtty_2"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="boxes_on_pallet_2"></input></td>
                        <td id="return_oldLocation2"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="sku_code_input_2" onchange="showOldLocations(this.value,this)"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="expected_qtty_box_2"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="received_box_qtty_2"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="putaway_area_2"></input></td></tr>

</table> <!-- End of SKU list table -->
</div> <!-- div for page to be printed -->  
<button type="button" id="row_button">Add New Row</button>

</div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thank you, finally this looks like the output I was looking for. Previously when I used that serializeArray() I was getting [object Object] instead of values. And in console I could not see any values only different options.

Comment: `[object Object]` is the default result of calling `.toString()` on an object. 
That also happens automatically when you try to concat the object with a string like this `console.log("output: " + someObject)` or like this `$('something').text(someObject)`. To inspect an object you should always use `console.log(someObject)` or `console.log("info", someObject)`.

Comment: Could I ask you for one more thing? Is it possible to make this as multidimensional array before it is sent to PHP? I would like to put on beggining values of  `container_noS, ic_numbS and date_and_time` + row count what was made on beggining of the function, what is sending all this data to PHP with `var countRow = $('#sku_details_list tr').length -3;`

Comment: @michal I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "multidimensional array" in this case. Can you provide a complete result so I can try figure out what exactly you want to achieve? You can add the wanted result as an edit to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize some table rows seperately you could maybe do something like this:

```js
// Helper function that serializes each input element 
// of a specified parent element.
var serialize = function(element) {
  return $(element).find(':input').get()
    .reduce(function(accu, field) {
      accu[field.name] = field.value;
      return accu;
    }, {});
};

var data = serialize('#rcv_head_tmpl'); // add base-table data
 
// add sub-table data as "rows"
data.rows = $("#sku_details_list") // find sub-table
  .find('tr:not(:first)') // get each row except the first (header)
  .get().map(serialize); // serialize each row

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="container-fluid" method="post" id="inboundList" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <div id="no-print" style="margin-left:10%;">
        <button type="button" id="save_button" style="margin: 0 20px 20px 0;" onclick="returnArrayValues()">Save</button>
        <button type="button" id="print_button" style="margin: 0 20px 20px 0;" onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
        <button type="reset" id="reset_button" style="margin: 0 20px 20px 0;">Reset Form</button>
        <button type="close" id="cancel_button" style="margin: 0 20px 20px 0;">Discard</button>
    
    </div>
    <div style="width:20.7cm;  background-color: yellow; page-break-inside:auto;  ;" id="printPageDiv"> <!-- Start of DIV what will be printed -->
    <div style="position:relative;"> <!-- Header of Page with logo and Container No. -->
    <img src='../../images/id_print_logo.png' height="72px" width="182px">
    <label>Created:<input type="datetime-local" step="60" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}" 
    id="create_time" name="create_time" readonly style="width:180px; text-align:center;" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i')?>"></input></label>
    
    <label style="font-size:15px;font_weight:bold;  margin-left: 20px">Container Number: 
        <input type="text" name="container_noS" id="container_noS" style="font-size:15px; font_weight:bold; text-align:center; width: 180px;" maxlength="16" required></input></label>
    </div>  
    <!-- IC Number with its Barcode  -->
    <div style="position:relative; margin-top:5px; height:2cm">
    <label style="float:right; font_weight:bold;width:250px; ">IC Number: <input required type="text" name="ic_numbS" id="ic_numbS" onchange="changeTest(this.form)" 
    maxlength="16" style="font-size:20px; font_weight:bold; text-align:center;"></input></label>
    <div id="insertBarcodeHere"></div>
    </div>  
<div class="row"></div> 
<table id="rcv_head_tmpl"> <!-- Start of header table -->
    <tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>Date: </th><th>Name: </th></tr>
    <tr><th>Client: </th><td><input type="text" name="customer_code"></input></td>
    <th>Unloading: </th><td><input type="date" name="unload_date"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="unload_name"></td></tr>
    
    <tr><th>Date and Time: </th><td><input type="datetime-local" step="60" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"  
    name="date_and_time" required></input></td>
    
    <th>Sorting: </th><td><input type="date" name="sorting_date"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sorting_name"></td></tr>
    
    <tr><th>Gate: </th><td><input type="text" name="gate_numbe"></input></td>
    <th>Put away: </th><td><input type="date" name="putaway_date"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="putaway_name"></td></tr>
    
    <tr><th>OLD RO: </th><td><input type="text" name="old_ro_numb"></input></td>
    <th>Confirmation: </th><td><input type="date" name="confirm_date"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="confirm_name"></td></tr>
    
    <tr><th></th><td></td>
    <th>Counting pcs in box: </th><td><input type="date" name="in_box_date"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="in_box_name"></td></tr>    

</table  > <!--end of header table -->
<table id="sku_details_list"  class="tablesorter" style=" border-spacing: 1px;"> <!-- Start of SKU list table -->

    <tr><th style="width: 3%;">ID: </th><th style="width: 8%;">Total Pallets: </th><th style="width: 8%;">Boxes on Pallet: </th><th style="width: 12%;">Old Location: </th>
    <th style="width: 20%;">SKU Code: </th><th style="width: 8%;">Expected Qtty: </th><th style="width: 8%;">Received Boxes: </th><th style="width: 12%;">Putaway Location: </th></tr>
    
    <tr><td>1</td><td><input type="text" name="pallets_qtty_1"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="boxes_on_pallet_1"></input></td>
                        <td id="return_oldLocation1"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="sku_code_input_1" onchange="showOldLocations(this.value,this)"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="expected_qtty_box_1"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="received_box_qtty_1"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="putaway_area_1"></input></td></tr>
        
    <tr><td>2</td><td><input type="text" name="pallets_qtty_2"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="boxes_on_pallet_2"></input></td>
                        <td id="return_oldLocation2"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="sku_code_input_2" onchange="showOldLocations(this.value,this)"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="expected_qtty_box_2"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="received_box_qtty_2"></input></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="putaway_area_2"></input></td></tr>

</table> <!-- End of SKU list table -->
</div> <!-- div for page to be printed -->  
<button type="button" id="row_button">Add New Row</button>

</div>
  </form>
```

I think it would be even easier if you would put each section into its own `form` element. Then you could just use `serializeArray` on each `form` element and finally combine the results.